# How to test the inclusion of a single random effect in glmer?

Tags: r, mixed-model

Suppose I have two models:

```
m1=glm(DV~IVs)
m2=glmer(DV~IVs+(1|Subject))
```

How can I test the inclusion of that random intercept in R? I know that I can't use logLikelihood tests to compare glm and glmer. I've come across RLRsim but that seems to only work for lm/lmer?

Comment: Is not model 1 the same as model 2 when the variance of the random effects is set equal to zero.  If so it would seem that a likelihood ratio test is applicable subject to the usual caveats about the term for the null hypothesis being on the boundary.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind filling me in on the caveats?

Comment: because it is one sided and there is a lot of religion about this. I had hoped some suitably equipped alcolyte would chip in.